# Object.values() not updating variable

Tags: javascript, variables

I have the variable `G.playerStatsDifference` defined as an array of objects:

```
playerStatsDifference: [{
        carpenter: 0,
        wood: 0,
        gunman: 0,
        gunpowder: 0,
        merchant: 0,
        gold: 0,
        fleet: 0,
        flagship: 0,
    }, {
        carpenter: 0,
        wood: 0,
        gunman: 0,
        gunpowder: 0,
        merchant: 0,
        gold: 0,
        fleet: 0,
        flagship: 0,
    }]
```

The point of this variable is to calculate the difference between `G.playerStats` which frequently changes.

My function to calculate the difference is:

```
const oldPlayerStats = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(G.playerStats));
statsDifference(G, oldPlayerStats);  

for (let p = 0; p < 2; p++) { 
    for (let s = 0; s < 8; s++) { 
        Object.values(G.playerStatsDifference[p])[s] = Object.values(G.playerStats[p])[s] - Object.values(oldPlayerStats[p])[s];
    }    
}
```

The expected output would be to have `playerStatsDifference`

When running some tests I did some console logging and it gave me the correct calculations, but the `G.playerStatsDiffence` would not update.

Here is some of that testing, with the calulations being correct:

```
console.log("Current wood is " + Object.values(G.playerStats[0])[1]); //Current wood is 5
console.log("Old wood is " + Object.values(oldPlayerStats[0])[1]); //Old wood is 10
console.log(Object.values(G.playerStats[0])[1] - Object.values(oldPlayerStats[0])[1]); //-5
```

I thought maybe I was doing something wrong with the loops so I tried the following afterwards:

```
Object.values(G.playerStatsDifference[0])[1] = Object.values(G.playerStats[0])[1] - Object.values(oldPlayerStats[0])[1];
```

However this did not work either. Having said that, the following does work:

```
G.playerStatsDifference[0].wood = Object.values(G.playerStats[0])[1] - Object.values(oldPlayerStats[0])[1];
```

So it seems like I have some issue with the `Object.values` on `G.playerStatsDifference`. Any idea on why that is and how I can run that through the loop?

=====

EDIT: As those in the comments have pointed out my question is a bit confusing so I will try to clear it up here..

The `G.playerStatsDifference` value is supposed to track the difference between the previous value of `G.playerStats` and the current value of `G.playerStats`.

To do this I am setting the value of `oldPlayerStats` to equal `G.playerStats` and then updating `G.playerStats` to its new value.

I then need to run through the array of objects and subtract the value of `G.playerStats` from `oldPlayerStats`. This will produce the value of `G.playerStatsDifference`

That is what the loop is for, to go through each object key and do the calculation.

Hope this provides some clarity. Sorry for the poorly worded question.

Comment: `Object.values` is a static method of the root `Object` class. You can't assign to it. It also makes no sense to call it with the result of a math operation like subtraction.

Comment: So `playerStatsDifference` grows in size with every new playerStats announced?

Comment: @AndrewParks No, the values get replaced/updated.

Comment: You seem to have Object.values all over the place.  It doesn’t do what you think.

Comment: @JaredSmith That's for pointing that out, what are some alternative approaches?

Comment: So playerStatsDifference contains the last two sets of differences?

Comment: @AndrewParks It should contain the difference between the current value and the old value. As the others are pointing out, it seems like I am misusing object.values

Comment: @evilgenious448 I mean no offense when I say this (we all start somewhere, and you don't get better by not trying) but your approach is so broken I can't really understand what you're trying to accomplish. Maybe edit the question to include more background?

Comment: But if it contains the difference between the current and old, why are there two objects in there? Why not only one?

Comment: @JaredSmith All good, I will edit the question to try to make it more clear. No offence taken, appreciate you being polite with your response :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const diffBetweenObjectValues = (a, b) => {
  return Object.entries(a).reduce((result, [aKey, aVal]) => {
    result[aKey] = aVal - (b[aKey] ?? 0);
    return result;
  }, {});
}

const stats = { a: 1, b: 2 };
const updatedStats = { a: 1, b: 1 };

// Initial player stats are { a: 1, b: 2 }
const player = { stats: stats, diff: {} };

// Set the diff, value is { a: 0, b: 1 }
player.diff = diffBetweenObjectValues(player.stats, updatedStats);

// Actually update the stats, value is { a: 1, b: 1 }
player.stats = updatedStats;
```

Note that if a key is present in `b` but not `a` it's ignored. Also note that this *only* works properly if all the property values are numeric.

You can put the state transition in a function and just run it when you need to update the stats (like every tick of the game loop).

## Response to comment

Ok, lets add another helper function

```
const zip = (a, b) => a.map((x, i) => [x, b[i]]);

const players = [...]; // array of players
const statUpdates = [...];   // array of stat updates
zip(players, statUpdates).forEach(([player, stats]) => {
  player.diff = diffBetweenObjectValues(player.stats, stats);
  player.stats = stats;
});
```

Zip combines the array of players and the array of stat updates in to pairs, then iterate over them with `forEach`, destructure the bits back out, and run the update. You can also just use a for loop, which is faster but harder to read and easier to get wrong (e.g. off-by-one errors). I would stick with the version until/unless your profiler tells you it's too slow.

### Update 2

```
const currentStats = [{ a: 1, b: 2 }, {a: 3, b: 2 }];
const updatedStats = [{ a: 0, b: 1 }, {a: 4, b: 1 }];
const diffedStats = zip(currentStats, updatedStats).map(([current, updated]) => {
  return diffBetweenObjectValues(current, updated);
});
```

Comment: Hey Jared, just trying to wrap my head around this answer. Also, what would be right way to go about having the `stats` be an array with 2 objects, where `stats[0]` is the stats for the first player and `stats[1]` is the stats for the second player

Comment: @evilgenious448 see my edit to the answer.

Comment: Hey @Jared Smith, sorry for the delay with my reply, have been trying to integrate your solution into my code. The values for `stats` and `updatedStats` would be coming through as: 
`const stats = [{ a: 1, b: 2 }, { a: 1, b: 2 }];
    const updatedStats = [{ a: 1, b: 1 }, { a: 1, b: 1 }];`
If I am correct in my understanding, your solution does not quite work with the values as 2 objects in an array.

Comment: @evilgenious448 Generally it is mistake to structure you code that way except in [AAA gamedev in C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AoS_and_SoA) and not even always there. In object-oriented code the object should own their state, player stats should be *properties of player objects*, not an array of separate entities linked up by position in the array. I think part of the reason people are having a hard time grokking your question is that basically no experienced developer would design it that way (again, no offense intended).

Comment: all good, again no offence taken. I am actually using a framework that requires the players to be structured like this (guess it's not a very good framework haha).

Comment: @evilgenious448 I would guess that it was designed by someone coming from AAA gamedev using C++ where structuring things that way makes sense to improve cache miss rates. But this isn't C++ it's Javascript, and very **very** few hand-written JS games need that level of performance concern. AFAIK high performance JS games are usually written in something else (e.g. C++ with SDL, C# in Unity) then compiled to human-unreadable JS or even WASM.

Comment: Ah ok, that's valuable to know. Maybe for the next game, I will look at a more suitable framework. Are you able to amend your answer to match the array/object structure?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249766/discussion-between-evilgenious448-and-jared-smith).

Comment: Just want to add one final comment that @Jared Smith is definitely someone StackOverflow needs more people to be like. Went above and beyond trying to help me, even when I was probably biting of a bit more than I could chew, he was patient and polite and helped me get to where I need to be. Wish I could give him all 500 of my points, he deserves them.

Answer (score 1):

```js
// for testing purposes, create an object with some random stats
const randomPlayerStats = () => Object.fromEntries(
  ['carpenter','wood','gunman','gunpowder','merchant','gold','fleet','flagship']
    .map(k=>[k,Math.random()*10|0]));

// array of the last player stats recorded for each player
let lastPlayerStats = [];

// create a new object from the existing object, subtracting each entry
// from the old object from the entry from the new object
// note: uses the ?? operator so that if there is no last object yet,
// the last object value will be treated as being zero
const difference = (playerStats, lastPlayerStats) => {
  let r = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(playerStats).map(([k,v])=>
    [k, v-(lastPlayerStats?.[k]??0)]));
  lastPlayerStats = playerStats;
  return r;
};

// simulate 5 rounds of the game, with 2 players in the game
const playerCount = 2;
const simulatedRounds = 5;
for(let c=0;c<simulatedRounds;c++) {
  let playerStats = [...Array(playerCount).keys()].map(i=>randomPlayerStats());
  let playerStatsDifference = playerStats.map((s,i)=>
    difference(s, lastPlayerStats[i]??{}));
  console.log('playerStats:');
  console.log(playerStats);
  console.log('playerStatsDifference:');
  console.log(playerStatsDifference);
}
```

Comment: Hey @Andrew Parks, are you able to edit the answer to output the difference in the same structure as the stats. So `{
  "carpenter": 4,
  "wood": 0,
  "gunman": 6,
  "gunpowder": 8,
  "merchant": 0,
  "gold": 8,
  "fleet": 5,
  "flagship": 5
}`

Comment: @evilgenious448 oops, fixed

Comment: @AndrewParks you really need to add some explanation to this wall of code. It's not really useful in its current state.

Comment: @evilgenious448 I finally understand why playerStatsDifference had multiple entries - it's a multiplayer game. My answer now works for a multiplayer game

Comment: Hi @Andrew Parks, sorry I should have explained that it is a multiplayer game with 2 players. Thank you for editing your answer. It seems to work exactly how I want it. But your code is a bit new to me, so I would appreciate it if you could put some comments and saw what certain parts of the code do.